# AWS Lambda function that returns a Textract result works during the Test Simulator but not live

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, amazon-textract

I have two Lambda functions behind API Gateways that work independently without issue.

Lambda 1 ([AWS Textract](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/sync-calling.html)): Takes an image URL (via byte stream) and gets the document text from it.
Lambda 2: Eventually calls Lambda 1 with a derived URL. The rest of this function is unimportant.

Lambda 1 works 100% of the time when I test it with Visual Studio or in the Lambda Function Test Simulator. I can even use something like Insomnia or PostMan and get it to work.

"Work" means that I have successfully called the [Textract API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/sync-calling.html) and received back a response. What is weird is when I call Lambda 1 from Lambda 2, the call works and I get partial data back. The "Blocks" property of the Textract object is empty.

Here's Lambda 1

```
let bytes = getBytesFromUrl imageUrl
            let memStream = new MemoryStream(bytes)
            let client = new AmazonTextractClient("", "", Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast2)
            let request = new DetectDocumentTextRequest()
            let doc = new Document()
            doc.Bytes <- memStream
            request.Document <- doc
            let x = client.DetectDocumentTextAsync(request).Result
            x
```

Here's the Lamda 2's invocation

```
let InvokeLambda payload = 
        let l = new AmazonLambdaClient("", "")
        let req = new InvokeRequest()
        req.FunctionName <- "Lambda1Name"
        req.InvocationType <- InvocationType.RequestResponse
        req.Payload <- payload
        let response = l.InvokeAsync(req).Result
        let sr = new StreamReader(response.Payload)
        let x = sr.ReadToEnd()
        x
```

Anyone feeling up for digging into this with me?

Comment: So, apparently there's an issue with the image extension the API provides me. For some reason I receive an image with an extension of `.jpeg.jpg`. This is weird and when I use a different image, it appears to work when loaded from a computer, but not a device like a phone. So, I have some more digging to do.

Comment: So was it an issue with the API or textract? Did you figure it out?

Comment: It seems to be a combination. I can't figure out why the API is adding the extra extension, but the biggest issue came from reading the byte array. I wasn't asking for enough bytes and therefore it didn't read the whole image. However, I can't just `Int32.MaxValue` because it breaks with an error. So, I started with 9's and reduced until it was happy.